# call function before start other function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently red the documentation about laravel, "i think is a good framewrok but in my project i'm using codeigniter", there is [Request Lifecycle](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle) that how i understood it allow a call before start any other action, example is useful for check if the user is logged. My question is there is something similar on codeigniter framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be need to take a look at [Hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/hooks.html)